x64 and x86 folder is missing in PublishBuildArtifact@1 in Azure CI Pipeline
The solutions contain MVC Web App in .Net Framework 4.7.1. The service layer library project and API are in .Net Core 6.0
Azure CI pipeline use windows-2019 and CI published zip artifact has x64 and x86. The x64 has SNI.dll which is important for the MVC We app.
Migrated Library and API to .Net 8.0 and updated Azure CI pipeline to use windows-2022 or windows-latest. The published artifact does not have x64 and x86.
Reverted the migration and only updated the azure CI pool agent to windows-2022 and still i is not generated x64 and x86 folder.
Please advise how to publish with x64 and x86.
The configuration manager has Any CPU for all project.
Even I tried updating the Any CPU to x64 but it is not generating

This question is similar to: Failed to Load d:\test\SNI.dll system componentmodel.win32Exception: The specified model could not be found. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
